# Configuring WSO2 Identity Server with Office365 OAuth2 Federated Authentication to access MS Graph API

Tags: wso2-identity-server

How should WSO2 Identity Server be configured with Office365 Federated Authentication to access MS Graph API?

I followed the steps in the link below but not clear on how to get the access token to use for MS Graph API.

https://medium.com/@piraveenaparalogarajah/configuring-microsoft-azure-ad-authenticator-as-federated-idp-in-wso2-identity-server-f79f5e1d7222

The Playground2 app returns an ID Token which I tried using to access some endpoints using Postman but I'm getting invalid token.

Answer (score -1):

WSO2 Identity Server can connect to Office365 in several authentication mechanisms. You can refer [1] for more information.

[1] https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/logging-in-to-office365-using-wso2-identity-server/

Comment: Hi Shan,

Thanks for the link.

I followed the steps in the link below but not clear on how to get the access token to use for MS Graph API.

https://medium.com/@piraveenaparalogarajah/configuring-microsoft-azure-ad-authenticator-as-federated-idp-in-wso2-identity-server-f79f5e1d7222

The Playground2 app returns an ID Token which I tried using to access some endpoints using Postman but I'm getting invalid token.

Comment: @Norman, the blog post you are referring to does not cater to your requirement. The official documentation link Shan has shared above is the correct approach.